# How can I get glossaries links to point to the right pages?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I am using the package **glossaries** to generate a list of acronyms and a list of symbols in a book. The links in the lists of acronyms and symbols which should point to page 1 in my document actually link to the title page and not to page 1 in the document. The other links point to the right pages.

Could someone help me figure out what I am not doing right. Thanks to everyone in advance.

Here is a MWE. (I hope it is not too big.)

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[acronym,section=chapter,nogroupskip,nomain,savewrites,xindy] {glossaries}
\newcommand{\notation}{Notation}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{hoo}{ntn}{\notation}
\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{isal}{ISAL}{Institute of Serengeti Animal Lovers}
\newacronym{iisal}{IISAL}{International Institute of Savannah Animal Lovers}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:animals}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{A}},%
    description=The set of all animals in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=A%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:lions}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{L}},%
    description=The set  of all lions in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=L%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:gnus}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{G}},%
    description=The set of all gnus in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=G%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:zebras}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{Z}},%
    description=The set of all zebras in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=Z%
}

\begin{document}

\title{My Book Title}

\author{My Name}

\maketitle


\frontmatter{}


\chapter*{Preface}

The preface to my book.

\tableofcontents{}

\cleardoublepage{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymname}

\printacronyms

\cleardoublepage{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\notation}

\printglossary[style=long3col, type=notation,
title=\notation] 

\mainmatter{}

\chapter{Introduction}

The subject of this book is about a problem that was once posed by
the \gls{isal}. The \gls{isal} is an affiliate of the \gls{iisal}.

There is an ecosystem called the Serengeti which comprises the set
\gls{hoo:animals} of which \gls{hoo:gnus}, \gls{hoo:lions} and
\gls{hoo:zebras} are subsets. We are interested in how subsets of
the subsets of \gls{hoo:animals} maintain equilibrium in the ecosystem.

\chapter{Interactions in the Savannah}

Members of \gls{hoo:lions} devour members of \gls{hoo:gnus} and
\gls{hoo:zebras}. Members of \gls{hoo:gnus} and \gls{hoo:zebras}
compete for some types of food but bunch up together to increase their
security against predation by members of \gls{hoo:lions}.

\backmatter{}

\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem can be solved simply moving

```
\maketitle
```

after

```
\frontmatter
```

where it belongs.

Also note that commands like `\frontmatter`, `\tableofcontents` don't take argumets.

Moreover, things like

```
\cleardoublepage{}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\notation}
```

are not needed. You simply have to add the option `toc` when loading `glossaries`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[acronym,section=chapter,nogroupskip,nomain,savewrites,toc,xindy] {glossaries}
\newcommand{\notation}{Notation}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{hoo}{ntn}{\notation}
\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{isal}{ISAL}{Institute of Serengeti Animal Lovers}
\newacronym{iisal}{IISAL}{International Institute of Savannah Animal Lovers}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:animals}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{A}},%
    description=The set of all animals in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=A%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:lions}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{L}},%
    description=The set  of all lions in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=L%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:gnus}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{G}},%
    description=The set of all gnus in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=G%
}

\newglossaryentry{hoo:zebras}{%
    name=\ensuremath{\mathscr{Z}},%
    description=The set of all zebras in the Serengeti,%
    type=notation,%
    sort=Z%
}

\begin{document}

\title{My Book Title}

\author{My Name}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\chapter*{Preface}

The preface to my book.

\tableofcontents

\printacronyms

\printglossary[style=long3col, type=notation,
title=\notation]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

The subject of this book is about a problem that was once posed by
the \gls{isal}. The \gls{isal} is an affiliate of the \gls{iisal}.

There is an ecosystem called the Serengeti which comprises the set
\gls{hoo:animals} of which \gls{hoo:gnus}, \gls{hoo:lions} and
\gls{hoo:zebras} are subsets. We are interested in how subsets of
the subsets of \gls{hoo:animals} maintain equilibrium in the ecosystem.

\chapter{Interactions in the Savannah}

Members of \gls{hoo:lions} devour members of \gls{hoo:gnus} and
\gls{hoo:zebras}. Members of \gls{hoo:gnus} and \gls{hoo:zebras}
compete for some types of food but bunch up together to increase their
security against predation by members of \gls{hoo:lions}.

\backmatter

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot **karlkoeller**. I have tried out your MWE. It works wonderfully well. The comment on using the **toc** option is a very useful lesson to me. The problems about the relative positions of **\maketitle** and **\frontmatter**, and about the arguments to **\frontmatter** and **\tableofcontents**, are due to the export of my MWE from LyX. I have to figure out how to get LyX sort them out. The rest of the problems were due to my ignorance. Thanks, once more, for your prompt response and for showing me how to get it right.

Comment: @user24098 You're welcome. Glad to have helped you.