# Acronym back-link to section

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, glossaries, acronyms

How to tweak `acronym` such that the back-link points to the **Section** and not to the *page*?

Consider the MWE. The acronym printed is:
[image]

But I want links to be at `1.1` and `1.3` respectively (to the corresponding sections).

***MWE***

```
% Partially copied from
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231811/how-can-i-get-glossaries-links-to-point-to-the-right-pages

\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeindex
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage[acronym,section=chapter,nogroupskip,nomain,savewrites,toc,xindy] {glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{isal}{ISAL}{Institute of Serengeti Animal Lovers}
\newacronym{iisal}{IISAL}{International Institute of Savannah Animal Lovers}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Chap 1}
    \section{Sec 1}
    The subject of this book is about a problem that was once posed by
    the \gls{isal}. 
    \lipsum[1-3]    

    \section{Sec 2}
    \lipsum[4-6]

    \section{Sec 3}
    Again, the \gls{isal} is an affiliate of the \gls{iisal}.

    \printnoidxglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms},]  
\end{document}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Add `counter=section` in `\usepackage{glossaries}` option.